# Create a read more link within a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

To create a read more link in JavaScript, I use this function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
           function toggleContent(v) {
               var vbox = document.getElementById('vbox');
               vbox.style.display = v;
           }
    </script>

<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
<a href="javascript:toggleContent('block')"> read more </a> </p>

<p id="vbox" style="display: none"> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
<a href="javascript:toggleContent('none')"> less </a> </p>
```

Now, I want to use it in a loop so that it will be unique for each content in the loop. I want to apply it to comments pulled from a database table and use it like this:

```
<?php 
    $posts = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('display' => 'true'))->result_array();     
    foreach ($posts as $p) { ?>
        <p> <?php echo $p['comment_snippet']; ?>
        <a href="javascript:toggleContent('block')"> show full comment </a></p>
        <p id="vbox" style="display: none"> <?php echo $p['comment']; ?>
        <a href="javascript:toggleContent('none')"> less </a> </p>              
        <hr/>
<?php } ?>
```

When I try it as it is above, it only affects the first comment, no matter which one I click on. I don't know much JavaScript and I have tried reading about how JS loops work, but I do not know how to use it in this case. Also, I want the comment snippet to be hidden when the 'show full comment' link is clicked, and the comment hidden and comment snippet shown when the 'less' link is clicked.

I have tried using [this JQuery method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46296772/creating-a-read-more-link-inside-jquery-datatables-render-function), but it doesn't solve my problem (**I'm trying to implement this feature inside JQuery datatables with server side processing in Code Igniter, using the render function to format my data before display**). Please help me.

Comment: You just need to integrate the answer in your prev question, or use a `data-id=""` and a toggle class for the event handler, as you're trying to do it in datatables its only difference is your putting the html in the render callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a unique id for each vbox that you want to toggle. You can pass in the index of the loop to the id attribute and javascript method.

Update your JS and PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function toggleContent(id, v) {
           var vbox = document.getElementById(id);
           if (vbox) {
               vbox.style.display = v;
           }
       }
</script>
```

and

```
<?php 
    $index = 0;
    $posts = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('display' => 'true'))->result_array();     
    foreach ($posts as $p) { 
        $id = "vbox".$index;
?>
        <p> <?php echo $p['comment_snippet']; ?>
        <a href="javascript:toggleContent('<?php echo $id; ?>', 'block')"> show full comment </a></p>
        <p id="<?php echo $id; ?>" style="display: none"> <?php echo $p['comment']; ?>
        <a href="javascript:toggleContent('<?php echo $id; ?>', 'none')"> less </a> </p>              
        <hr/>
<?php  $index++; } ?>
```

Comment: This solved my problem ultimately! Thanks itodd. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to do this. I think that the simplest one is instead of have the element fixed:

```
var vbox = document.getElementById('vbox');
```

You can use the element that is closes to the current element that was clicked.

```js
function toggleContent(el, v) {
  debugger;
  vbox = $(el).closest('.readmore-container').find('.readmorecontent')[0]
  vbox.style.display = v;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="readmore-container">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleContent(this, 'block')"> read more </a> </p>

  <p id="vbox" style="display: none" class="readmorecontent"> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleContent(this, 'none')"> less </a> </p>  
</div>

<div class="readmore-container">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleContent(this, 'block')"> read more </a> </p>

  <p id="vbox" style="display: none" class="readmorecontent"> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleContent(this, 'none')"> less </a> </p>  
</div>

<div class="readmore-container">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleContent(this, 'block')"> read more </a> </p>

  <p id="vbox" style="display: none" class="readmorecontent"> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleContent(this, 'none')"> less </a> </p>  
</div>
```

> I changed the markup to include a container and also used `onclick` and `this` to pass the relevant element to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing cue from the accepted answer (itodd's), I was able to modify the code to toggle the visibility of the comment snippet depending on the visibility of the full comment. This is crucial since the snippet is also part of the full comment (unless otherwise structured). So generally, when the 'show full comment' link is clicked, it hides the snippet (including the 'show full comment' link text) and shows the full comment. In similar fashion, when the 'less' link is clicked, it shows the snippet (including the 'show full comment' link text) and hides the full comment. Still new to JavaScript but itodd's answer was quite insightful. I hope someone finds it useful. Here is the modification:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function showFullComment(s, h) {
       var comment = document.getElementById(s);
       var snippet = document.getElementById(h);
       if (comment && snippet) {
           comment.style.display = 'block';
           snippet.style.display = 'none';
       }
   }

   function showLessComment(s, h) {
       var comment = document.getElementById(s);
       var snippet = document.getElementById(h);
       if (comment && snippet) {
           comment.style.display = 'none';
           snippet.style.display = 'block';
       }
   }
</script>

<?php 
$index = 1;
$posts = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('display' => 'true'))->result_array();
foreach ($posts as $p) { 
    $s = "comment".$index; 
    $h = "snippet".$index; ?>
    <p id="<?php echo $h; ?>"> <?php echo $p['snippet']; ?><br/>
    <a href="javascript:showFullComment('<?php echo $s; ?>', '<?php echo $h; ?>')"> show full comment </a></p>
    <p id="<?php echo $s; ?>" style="display: none"> <?php echo $p['comment']; ?><br/>
    <a href="javascript:showLessComment('<?php echo $s; ?>', '<?php echo $h; ?>',)"> less </a> </p>              
    <hr/>
<?php  $index++; } ?>
```